# PHP - finfo class not found. unable to upload file after deploying site online

Tags: php

I am building a web application using ExtJS4 and PHP5. There is a part where I upload a photo and as I was testing it locally, I am able to upload photos properly to a folder in the file directory.

After I deployed the file to our server online, I tested it. At first, I was getting a `class finfo not found`, at it pointed to my `upload.php` file and and to the line:

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
```

Upon googling the problem, I needed to make sure that my php.ini file allowed file uploads. So what I did was I made my own `php.ini` file in the server and I copy pasted the contents from the php.ini file located in `../MAMP/conf/php5.5.10/php.ini` but I got an error that I'm trying to decode an invalid JSON String. I also tried `../MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/conf/php.ini` but I still get the same error.

I don't understand what's happening. I think I'm copying the wrong php.ini file to my server. I am using Freehostia and we are not allowed to access the php.ini file and it was advised to create my own php.ini file. However, so far, copy pasting my php.ini file did not work. It may be that I'm constructing the file wrong.

It's the fist time I've deployed a site that required a file upload, usually I just work with database CRUD and that works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a PHP Settings Page in the home page. I set the PHP to 5.5 and made sure it allowed file uploading.